# How to run selenium test on aws ec2 server

Tags: java, linux, selenium, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have dome with some basic selenium test and it is working fine on local machine, now i want ot run it on aws ec2 server ( Amazon Server). I have install selenium, firefox and other required libraries on aws but when i am running my code on aws i am getting some error that "Could not start a new session".

**My small selenium code**

```
    String platform_name = "linux";
    String browser_name = "firefox";
    String browser_version = "41";
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
    capabilities.setBrowserName(browser_name);
    capabilities.setVersion(browser_version);
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://ec2-52-34-44-185.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    System.out.print("url has been openening now...");
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    System.out.print("url has been open");
    driver.quit();
```

**Here is error which i am getting**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'napendra-PC', ip: '192.168.0.67', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:20)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to ec2-52-34-44-185.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4444 [ec2-52-34-44-185.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/52.34.44.185] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: is your hub able to establish connection with the node. Try  [hub](http://localhost:4444/grid/console) at your hub machine.

if not, you're having a networking issue. try to find out if ports are blocked.

Comment: @BorisStoyanov when i am opening hub on machine, nothing is opening, can you please give me some more direction.

Comment: Login at the machine where your hub is running, open the browser and paste the url. If nothing is opened please provide the log when you start your hub server.

Comment: Please cross check security group of ec2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never - It appears you dont have rights to access the port from your IP address.